# Trying to have a function return a simple number, it returns something else

Tags: c

I'm discovering this language and code in general. I'm trying to understand how fuction return numbers. My goal is to have a function do an easy calculation and return the result, then display the result through the printf function.

Here's what I tried :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int test1(int number1);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int number1 = 2;


    test1(number1);
    printf("%d\n", test1);

    return 0;
}

int test1(int number1)
{
    number1 += 2;
    printf("%d\n", number1);
    return number1;
    
}
```

It runs, and displays this :

```
4
14226428
```

I can't figure out why. The displayed 4 show that test1 runs and calculate correctly, but for some reason it returns something that it shouldn't. I suspect it's an adress but I can't find a way to make it return the value I'm looking for.

I managed to do it with a *void* function, as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void test1(int *number1);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int number1 = 2;


    test1(&number1);
    printf("%d\n", number1);

    return 0;
}

void test1(int *number1)
{
    *number1 += 2;
    
}
```

When this runs it displays a 4 as expected, yet I don't understand why it doesn't work with my *int* function. Could someone try to explain me *slowly* why it does that ? Thank you \o/

Comment: You need to assign the return value of your function to something. For example `int x = test1(number1); printf("%d\n", x);`

Comment: 0) turn on the maximum warnings your compiler can emit. Mind those warnings. 1) try `printf("%d\n", test1(&number1));`... `test1` by itself yields the address of the function (exact same as `&test1`).

Comment: You are printing `test1` (which is a function), not `number1`.

Comment: C is pass by value.  Calling `test(number1)` makes a copy of the value of `number1` but doesn't change the value of the variable `number1`.  The fact that you have also called the argument `number1` in your code for `test` makes it more confusing but it's a different object.  You also return the new value, and could get it that way (`number1 = test(number1);` but instead you ignore the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first implementation is fine, your test function is doing its job (manipulating the value and returning the updated value), but you are not printing the returned value from the function.

You have called the function as `test(number1)`, but haven't saved the returned value anywhere.

for example, the correct code would look like this:

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int number1 = 2;

        int result = test1(number1);

        printf("%d\n", result);

        return 0;
}
```

**OR**

If you don't want to save the value in a variable you can just directly call the function

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int number1 = 2;

        printf("%d\n", test1(number1));

        return 0;
}
```

Remember, to call a function `()` parentheses are important.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I didn't understand that the () were a full part of the function's name. I thought they were there just to call the arguments.

Comment: @NonoNunu if you try to print the value *without* the parentheses, you are not calling the function, but rather getting a pointer to the function. (And such, you are using the wrong format specifier, `"%p"` with a `(void *)test1`; the compiler should have warned you.)